# ArrayList передать в Adapter(Android kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin

столкнулся с такой, проблемой надо передать ArrayList из объекта(там содержится только String) в Adapter.
Код который у меня:

Adapter:

```
class AdapterC (val countryList: Collection<Countries>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterC.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
    val v = LayoutInflater.from(p0?.context).inflate(R.layout.country_list,p0,false)
    return  ViewHolder(v)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return countryList.size
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(p0: ViewHolder, p1: Int) {
    val country : Countries=countryList.toTypedArray()[p1]
    p0?.textViewName.text=country.name
}


class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView){
    val textViewName= itemView.findViewById(R.id.TextViewCountry) as TextView
}}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
val adapter= AdapterC(Collections.emptyList<Countries>())

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    val recyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recyclerView) as RecyclerView
    recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayout.VERTICAL,false)

    recyclerView.adapter=adapter
}
```

И функция где пытаюсь записать значение которые получил в Adapter:

```
  private  fun handleJson(jsonString:String?){
    val jsonResult = JSONObject(jsonString)
    val resultobject=jsonResult.getJSONObject("results")
    val list =ArrayList<Countries>()
    var iter=resultobject.keys()

    iter.forEach {
        var country = resultobject.getJSONObject(it)
        var name = country.optString("name")
        var item=Countries(name)
        list.add(item)
    }
    //   adapter.countryList.submitList(list)  <-- Подсвечивает красным SubmitList
    //   adapter.countryList.clear() <-- Подсвечивает красным clear
    //   adapter.countryList.addAll(list) <-- Подсвечивает красным addList
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы.
В Adaptere поменять значение

```
class AdapterC (val countryList: Collection<Countries>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterC.ViewHolder>() {
override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
```

На

```
class AdapterC (val countryList: ArrayList<Countries>): RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterC.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(p0: ViewGroup, p1: Int): ViewHolder {
```

В MainActivity

```
val adapter= AdapterC(Collections.emptyList<Countries>())
```

на

```
val adapter= AdapterC(arrayListOf<Countries>())
```

И тогда это заработает

```
adapter.countryList.clear()
adapter.countryList.addAll(list)
```